# Pseudo-MEAN app - Angular 2 Node Api

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, azure

This question comes in two parts based on how it has to work in production.

Objective:

- Create Angular 2 web app (SPA) that calls the api
- NodeJS API (RESTful)
- MongoDB
- Host on Azure

Here's the first question:

1. To host on Azure and hopefully use Continuous Deployment from github, would I have to create two Azure Web Apps?  One for the Angular 2 app, and one for the NodeJS API?
2. Or can I integrate the RESTful NodeJS API into the application with the Angular 2 app?  This would probably only require one web app in Azure.  If this is possible, I'm confused as to how to execute both the API and the Angular 2 app on Azure.  It seems the command "npm start" usually starts the Angular 2 app, but can the NodeJS API be launched as well?

Any clarity for this is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are too many possibilities here, with many architectures possible.

But to answer your question, yes, it is possible to have one monolithic application with an Angular 2 Front End and a NodeJS RSTful backend with a MongoDB instance

The options are:

- Have a monolith with the above mentioned configuration. The pro is that it's going to be easier to implement and deploy. If your app is super simple and low traffic, you can go with this approach.
- Have a layered architecture with a Front End Angular 2 app, an API layer with NodeJS and maybe Express.  A cloud MongoDB instance or cluster on any provider, like MongoLabs for your data layer. This allows for selective scaling of your layers according to traffic. If you're in a larger team, each team can work on it's own layer.

Comment: In Azure, let's say, what would be the easiest and less expensive deployment?  I'm thinking your first bullet point since both layers are integrated into the single monolithic application.  For the second bullet point, in Azure, would two web app instances be necessary for this scenario (adding to the cost)?  One for the Angular 2 app, and one for the NodeJS API?  MongoLabs or MongoDB Atlas are my current choices.

Comment: The least expensive would be the monolith, as you need to have only one app and one Mongo instance running (if you _dont_ want to scale up). You can scale up if you want but you'll need to scale up your entire application, and not your UI layer or your API layer selectively as is possible in approach #2

Comment: And yes, as you guessed, if it's a layered architecture, the overhead is that you will need at least one instance of your web app and one instance of your API layer running. And yes, this will add to the cost

Comment: That's what I figured, but wasn't sure.  Thanks for the answer.